# Замена текста по списку в VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

Подскажите, пожалуйста, возможно ли в VSCode как-то заменить текст по заранее сформированному списку соответствий?
Ну, например:

```
A → а
B → б
C → ц
```

Желательно, чтобы какие-то значения искались как прямое совпадение, а какие-то - как совпадение с заданными регулярными выражениями.
Может быть, есть готовые расширения для такого или же можно написать сниппет?
Попробовал сделать сниппет сам:

```
"body": [

                                            "${TM_SELECTED_TEXT/&#1040;/А/g}",

                                            "${TM_SELECTED_TEXT/&#1072;/а/g}",

                                            "${TM_SELECTED_TEXT/&#1041;/Б/g}",
```

далее аналогично для каждой буквы. (Эта часть должна преобразовывать в коде html entities в нормальный текст).
Но в таком виде сниппет каждой строкой выполняет одно преобразование для всего текста и дублирует весь текст. Видимо, надо как-то весь список загнать в одну конструкцию, но я не знаю, как.

Синтаксис для сниппета брал вот [отсюда](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets#_transform-examples), но там довольно скудное описание и маловато примеров, чтобы разобраться, практикуясь.

Comment: Не понимаю, при чём тут сниппеты. Вам явно нужен [Find and Replace](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics#_find-and-replace). Вот ещё [with regular expressions](https://blog.devsense.com/2022/find-and-replace-with-regexp).

Comment: Я не готов делать Find and Replace 67 раз руками для каждого рабочего файла. В том-то и задача, чтобы автоматизировать эту процедуру по готовому списку.
Возможно, непосредственно декодинг html entities в обычный текст можно выполнить как-то иначе (тоже не нашел, увы), но и в целом хотелось бы разобраться, как выполнять замену по готовому списку.

Comment: Сделайте поиск и замену сразу по всему проекту.

Comment: Это не проект в классическом понимании. Это файлы из Sharepoint Designer, которые периодически нужно редактировать, но при извлечении простым копированием ломается кодировка.
Вот удалось добраться до кода, но там вместо исходного русскоязычного текста - html entities.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=html+entities

Comment: К сожалению, все попадающиеся мне посты не дают понимания, как прицепить какое-то решение непосредственно к VSCode. Чтобы декодинг выполнялся там, а не где-то снаружи при помощи JS, Python или чего-то еще.

Answer (score 0):

Гугл не помог, а вот ChatGPT подсобил. В итоге сформировали с ним вот такую строку:

```
${TM_SELECTED_TEXT/(&#1040;)|(&#1072;)|(&#1041;)|(&#1073;)|(&#1042;)|(&#1074;)|(&#1043;)|(&#1075;)|(&#1044;)|(&#1076;)|(&#1045;)|(&#1077;)|(&#1025;)|(&#1105;)|(&#1046;)|(&#1078;)|(&#1047;)|(&#1079;)|(&#1048;)|(&#1080;)|(&#1049;)|(&#1081;)|(&#1050;)|(&#1082;)|(&#1051;)|(&#1083;)|(&#1052;)|(&#1084;)|(&#1053;)|(&#1085;)|(&#1054;)|(&#1086;)|(&#1055;)|(&#1087;)|(&#1056;)|(&#1088;)|(&#1057;)|(&#1089;)|(&#1058;)|(&#1090;)|(&#1059;)|(&#1091;)|(&#1060;)|(&#1092;)|(&#1061;)|(&#1093;)|(&#1062;)|(&#1094;)|(&#1063;)|(&#1095;)|(&#1064;)|(&#1096;)|(&#1065;)|(&#1097;)|(&#1066;)|(&#1098;)|(&#1067;)|(&#1099;)|(&#1068;)|(&#1100;)|(&#1069;)|(&#1101;)|(&#1070;)|(&#1102;)|(&#1071;)|(&#1103;)|(\\[%|%\\])/${1:+А}${2:+а}${3:+Б}${4:+б}${5:+В}${6:+в}${7:+Г}${8:+г}${9:+Д}${10:+д}${11:+Е}${12:+е}${13:+Ё}${14:+ё}${15:+Ж}${16:+ж}${17:+З}${18:+з}${19:+И}${20:+и}${21:+Й}${22:+й}${23:+К}${24:+к}${25:+Л}${26:+л}${27:+М}${28:+м}${29:+Н}${30:+н}${31:+О}${32:+о}${33:+П}${34:+п}${35:+Р}${36:+р}${37:+С}${38:+с}${39:+Т}${40:+т}${41:+У}${42:+у}${43:+Ф}${44:+ф}${45:+Х}${46:+х}${47:+Ц}${48:+ц}${49:+Ч}${50:+ч}${51:+Ш}${52:+ш}${53:+Щ}${54:+щ}${55:+Ъ}${56:+ъ}${57:+Ы}${58:+ы}${59:+Ь}${60:+ь}${61:+Э}${62:+э}${63:+Ю}${64:+ю}${65:+Я}${66:+я}/g}
```

Сперва он пошел тем же путем, что и я - несколько инструкций в ряд. Но быстро исправился и предложил вариант с перечислением.
Дальше я попросил его дописать строку с двух букв (на которых тренировались) до всего алфавита. На этом он снова застопорился и начал предлагать какие-то, якобы, универсальные варианты для преобразования html entities в обычный текст. Но они не работали. Тогда я скормил ему список сопоставлений код-буква, после чего он выполнил полную сборку.
И далее самый крупный затык возник на том, что я попросил добавить в код удаление "[%" и "%]". Вернее, вначале я хотел, чтобы конструкция [%**текст**%] заменялась на **текст**.
Он все время пытался выполнить эту операцию, как-то пришпиливая ее отдельно, из-за чего не срабатывал весь код. Даже, когда я уже просто предложил убирать по отдельности "[%" и "%]". Тогда я предложил менять их на пустую строку. Но тут он тоже выдавал вариант, который не работал, типа ${1:+} - при применении [% менялось на текст ${1:+}, видимо, из-за отсутствия значения для замены.
И дальше уже, больше сам, путем экспериментов дошел, что, если вообще убрать конструкцию для замены, то найденное значение будет просто удаляться.
В итоге, какое-то решение найдено. Правда, на данный момент задачу оно целиком не решает, так как оказалось, что сниппет не срабатывает на больших кусках кода.
Если кто-то сможет подсказать оптимизацию или вообще иной путь, буду рад.

Upd. Если заменить TM_SELECTED_TEXT на CLIPBOARD, то получается обрабатывать текст большого объема.
Копируем код из исходника, далее в VSCode не вставляем сразу, а вызываем сниппет, вставляется отредактированный код.
Возможно, кому-то пригодится для обработки и по другим шаблонам.

Comment: Для меня остаётся загадкой, куда вы это вставляете.

Comment: Это вставляется в файл пользовательских сниппетов.
Выглядит примерно так (пока не оформлял окончательно):
"convert text": {
// "scope": "HTML",
"prefix": "ccc",
"body": [список замен],
"description": ""
},
список замен - список из моего ответа. Далее выделяем кусок кода, который нужно причесать, набираем "ccc", жмем таб. Возвращается кусок кода с выполненными заменами.
Но, вот как минус - на большом объеме, оказалось, не работает.

Comment: Извините, если кого обидел упоминанием бота (минус у ответа). Я тут новичок, не знаю традиций.
Буду рад, если подскажете лучшее решение.